# Is repository pattern for MVC advisable for enterprise applications without Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

Is repository pattern for MVC with ADO.NET and without Entity Framework advisable?

Comment: **YES** - the `Repository` pattern is in no way or shape tied or connect to using Entity Framework. Using the `Repository` pattern makes sense - regardless of how you access your data in the end ...

Answer (score 0):

## **Yes, absolutely.**

Repository pattern has nothing to do with `EntityFramework`, it's just that EntityFramework makes a few things easy to work it.

Currently, I am using the same pattern in an enterprise application, few repositories uses `Dapper` where a little performance can be compromised, but at rest places bare `ADO.NET` is used, you just need to write a extra lines of codes.